# how to play Push notification text using speech?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, text-to-speech

I want to play coming push notification text in android using Text to speech control. whenever push notification generate in my device that time application is close so I want to play push notification text using text to speech without opening application.

Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use a service for any background tasks[image](slideshare.net)

> A Service is an application component representing either an
>   application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not
>   interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other
>   applications to use. Each service class must have a corresponding
>   declaration in its package's AndroidManifest.xml. Services can be
>   started with Context.startService() and Context.bindService().

So basically, its just something that runs in the background, including when the screen is off. Now, all you have to do, is put your TTS (text to speech) code in a service. That's easy, just implement the Text to Speech API and speak:

```
        TextToSpeech t1;
        t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

obviously, there are callback methods that have not been implemented in the preceding example, but here are the references (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html)

**If you are starting the notification from a broadcast receiver, you can simply call `startService()` from the receiver, or add the TTS code in the broadcast receiver (although that would be bad practice since broadcast receivers are solely meant to receive)**

If you need any more help, feel free to ask.

Comment: Can you let me know, why you need to implement your own service and not just start the TTS service when the notification is received instead?